# Regex expression for full path

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, vb.net

Regex expression for validating full path of an exe. I have little understanding of regex.

For example : if exe path is

```
C:\Programs\Files\User\Location\Sample.exe
```

or

C:\Sample.exe

or

```
C:\programs\sample.exe
```

ie. need a regex to valid full path of an exe.

If it is not having full path of an exe, it should catch that as an error.

Comment: Try using _splitpath() or its equivalent.

Comment: This doesnt sound like a Regex job.  This sounds like a `System.IO.Path` job.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.110).aspx Path.GetFullPath  Or more specifically to see if the path is full on network or local, use IsPathRooted  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.ispathrooted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I want to validate this in .aspx page, having regularexpression validator and controltovalidate will be one option.

Comment: Also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx Path.GetExtension

Comment: in short, this cannot be solved with regexp alone, without taking into account all of the known invalid character combinations and path structures. this must be done with `IO.Path`, with some sort of `regexp` sanity check, or string checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably shouldn't use a regular expression here. Simply ask the file system if the file exists.

If you are only looking for a valid path (not caring about whether it exists)

```
using System.IO;
var path = "";
if (path == Path.GetFullPath(path) && Path.GetExtension(path) == ".exe")
{
    //We have a valid path.
}
```

Comment: `.IsPathRooted` isn't totally reliable. you must do additional checks. ie: check the remarks section: it also works for `\\ ` UNC paths. also, it checks `.GetInvalidPathChars()`, so ` */:?\ ` will be allowed in the filename as well. i think there's a few other cases i can't remember.

Comment: or ie `C:\..\test.exe` returns True.. there's way too many cases to handle them all, but you need more code than that to even come close to an approximation ;p

Comment: @porkchop: Resolved the embedded `..`, not sure how to best solve the `\\` problem (especially since it may be okay for the user)

Comment: rofl. it even returns true for `1:\.\test.exe`. lol :D i'm telling you.. if you saw the block of code i have to test for paths, you would freak out. that's why i don't want to post it. bcs i haven't even fully tested it. what it needs is a regex sanity check. or a bunch of string checks.

Comment: @porkchop: Apparently it checks if the first char is a directory separator or the second char is a `:`. Nothing more.

Comment: it's best to keep your path and filename separate though. the checks are more reliable to an extent. and yes, it does check only the : colon, which is not specified in the documentation, which says it checks if it is a drive letter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple regex assuming you're matchin a Windows style path on the C drive (assumptions I made based on your examples):

```
([A-Z]:)?\\.*\.exe
```

Comment: this won't strip invalid characters or spaces in invalid locations, ie: `C:\ error \\ ` or `C:\\ ;:*?<> `

Comment: @Kita: Thanks.How do i make this to accept small c:\, right now it accepts only for C:\

Comment: @Kita you cannot fix this. you'd have to know all of the valid and invalid chars depending on OS and locale. that's only possible through `IO.Path` and extra checks.

Comment: @Kita: Thanks. I want to accept small letter C: drive too. Wit that it accepts C: or D:. ie..c:\sample.exe or C:\sample.exe - both should be okay.

Comment: @Wearwolf Please refrain from making edits that cause the rest of the answer to become confusing. Your edit is valid to an extent, but the answer still states that this solution is just for the C drive. This is no longer correct.

Comment: @ebarr Sorry, I was looking at the RegEx and didn't think about the rest of the answer.

Comment: ([a-zA-Z]:)?\\.*\.exe - this regex works for my scenario (for ex:C:\Sample.exe or c:\sample.exe.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 it will also work for `C:\<>:;?*\ .exe` which is invalid. it'll also match `\test\.exe` should be a {1} not a ?, but even then. this needs a 'club' approach. you need both `IO.Path`, with a regex sanity check, and maybe other checks on top of that.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 once the `IO.Path` filter passes, what you gotta watch out for are */:?\. but even that get complicated because `C:\a.b\test.exe` is valid, but `C:\.\test.exe` is not (well its valid in some contexts like cmd prompt, but not others). there are too many to list :D

Comment: @porkchop: Thanks, i agree with all your points, I was asked to use only regex, i will push back to use system.io.path.exists.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 use both. check using `IO.Path`. read docs on `.GetInvalidPathChars`, checks for most illegal chars, check for the extra ones i mentioned above using a regex `.Match`, another `.Match` similar to this post but way more complicated ;p to check the structure more. then another still, to check for any invalid path combinations involving the ` . ` (dot) character, since it has such a special syntax in folder/file structure. and if nobody answers your post by then, come back and answer your own question ;p

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern below check for valid local drives (c, d, ...), excluding UNC path (\...).

```
(?i)^[a-z]:\\[^/:*?"<>|]*[^\\]\.exe$
```

It will not accept invalid path characters and will fail if any of them present in the path. As you can see, the pattern accepts `exe` extension only. You can change it to any other extension or multiple extensions like below:

```
(?i)^[a-z]:\\[^/:*?"<>|]*[^\\]\.(?:exe|doc|txt)$
```

In this case, validation succeed if the file extension is either exe, doc or txt.

The `(?i)` switch at the beginning of the pattern turns off case-sensitivity. However, the switch only works for RegularExpressionValidator with `EnableClientScript="false"`. Otherwise, validation will be done on the client side using Javascript, which the switch is not recognized by the javascript regex engine. And there is no way to turn off case sensitivity.  In that case, you have to specify all possible match, upper or lower case:

```
^[a-zA-Z]:\\[^/:*?"<>|]*[^\\]\.(?:[eE][xX][eE]|[dD][oO][cC]|[tT][xX][tT])$
```

Answer (score -1):

Regex won't tell you if the full path to an individual EXE is valid or not, for example how can you possibly know if the file is there, or the directory, or for that matter the drive itself?

What you need is System.IO.File.Exists(xxxxxxxx);

Comment: @Sharpeye500 one last comment, this is a possible approach if you just want to read a file or save a file to disk. you can check if the folder exists, if it does, that means it's valid, then just check the filename using regex. if you want to read a file, just check if it exists directly. but you'd need to keep your path and filename in separate strings to check them that way.